# Need to create a Xconfig file- ubuntu 16

Tags: nvidia, video

So i need to create a xorg-config file and put it into the folder that holds the video configurations. I need the config to contain the following.

```
Section "ServerLayout"
   Identifier "layout"
   Screen 0 "nvidia"
   Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
   Identifier "nvidia"
   Driver "nvidia"
   BusID "PCI:2:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
   Identifier "intel"
   Driver "intel"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
   Identifier "nvidia"
   Device "nvidia"
EndSection
```

Can i get some assistance on how I would create such a file. This is to turn on my GTX 750ti on my external video card to PCI-E dock. I have been trying all night to get it to display onto my external monitor to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the file with any text editor, using `sudo` to obtain administrative permissions e.g.

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Then simply paste the contents in, and save.

If you want to use a GUI-based editor such as `gedit`, then make sure to add the `-H` parameter for the reasons described here [Why should users never use normal sudo to start graphical applications?](https://askubuntu.com/a/270019/178692)

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```